# find value of difference DISTINCT a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table, I run `count(capture_time)` on a column the result is 616606. Also, I run `count (DISTINCT capture_time)` on the same column the result is 580580.
Now, I want to see the value of the 36026 rows.(616606 - 580580 = 36026)
Which query I can use?

Comment: Do you want to see the rows where a specific capture_time exists multiple times? (If so you would need to use GROUP BY.)

Comment: @Björn Yes, exactly. Could you help me with how to use Group BY? I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY to group all identical capture_time values. Then you filter on those capture_time values which exist more than one time by using HAVING. Something like this:

```
select * from tablename where capture_time in(select capture_time from tablename group by capture_time having count(*) > 1)
```